# Windows Installer for UWP application

Tags: uwp, windows-installer, windows-10-universal

I developed one UWP application, How can I make installer for my application, using which I can install or uninstall the application.

Answer (score 1):

Review Microsoft's documentation on [Packaging, deployment, and query of Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446593), particularly the section on the [Package deployment API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh994436). This section contains two relevant samples:

- [Add app package sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236968)
- [App package removal sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236972)

If you are looking for an existing implementation of this, my employer offers a [commercial option](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/SteAppXPackages.htm), and I expect there are other options out there.

Comment: Please update your links, all of samples is invalid.